# How to use generics and inherit from parent class without causing name clash?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, abstract, name-clash

I have a parent class in Java called `Flight`. I have children classes: `JetFlight`, `NormalFlight`, etc. which inherit from `Flight`.

I want all the children classes to implement `compareTo` from the `Comparable` interface. I want them to inherit from `Flight` because I want to use polymorphism (for example, initiate a `Flight` array and fill it with objects of `JetFlight`, `NormalFlight`, etc.).

This is my code for the parent class:

```
public abstract class Flight  {
    public abstract int compareTo(Object o);
}
```

and this is the code for one of the children classes:

```
public class JetFlight extends Flight implements Comparable<JetFlight> {
    private int flightTime;
    public JetFlight(int flightTime) {
        this.flightTime = flightTime;
    }
    public int compareTo(JetFlight j) {
        return this.flightTime - j.flightTime;
    }
}
```

This code won't compile because of 2 errors:

1) `compareTo(T) in 'java.lang.Comparable' clashes with 'compareTo(Object)' in 'Flight'; both objects have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other.`

2) `Class 'JetFlight' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'compareTo(Object)' in 'Flight'`

How do I go about the situation when I want to inherit from a class and at the same time use generics on the child class?

Comment: You can't. If Flight implements Comparable<Flight> (why doesn't it, and why does it have a compareTo(Object) method instead?), then each and every flight must be comparable to any other Flight, whatever their actual type is. And if a JetFlight is only comparable to a JetFlight, then there shouldn't be a compareTo method in the base class: you won't be able to compare two Flights together anyway, since subclasses don't support it.

Comment: You might want to consider defining `Comparator`s for the specific subclasses, rather than trying to make the classes implement `Comparable`.

Comment: If every subclass of `Flight` is only comparable with other objects of the same subclass, then you can't sort a mixed `Flight[]` array.

Answer (score 2):

Option 1: Since your comparison is based upon flight time, and as far as I know, the variable 
`flightTime`
can be pushed up in the parent class as all flights will have this feature. Then implement your compareTo() method in parent class itself.

Option 2: in case you want to keep your current code the way it is:

```
    public abstract class Flight implements Comparable<Flight> {
    public abstract int compareTo(Flight o);
}
```

---

```
public class JetFlight extends Flight {
private int flightTime;
public JetFlight(int flightTime) {
    this.flightTime = flightTime;
}
public int compareTo(Flight f) {
    if(!(f instanceof JetFlight)){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    return this.flightTime - ((JetFlight)f).flightTime;
}
```

Comment: Your `compareTo` should throw `ClassCastException` in that case. `IllegalArgumentException` isn't declared. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T- That said, such a `compareTo` implementation is probably inappropriate to begin with. (See JB's comment under the question.)

Comment: @Radiodef agreed with the exception. But with the compareTo method, is there another option if OP insists on having the classes the way described in question? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can parameterize the `Comparable` on a type `T` bounded by `Flight`:

```
abstract class Flight<T extends Flight<T>> implements Comparable<T>  {
    public abstract int compareTo(T o);
}

class JetFlight extends Flight<JetFlight> {
    private int flightTime;
    public JetFlight(int flightTime) {
        this.flightTime = flightTime;
    }

    public int compareTo(JetFlight j) {
        return this.flightTime - j.flightTime;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you use Generics, you will get rid of the problem.

You need to define

```
public abstract int compareTo(JetFlight o);
```

and also use

```
public class JetFlight extends Flight implements Comparable<? extends JetFlight>
```

Comment: This doesn't compile.